# JavaScript value has quotations that are breaking the code

Tags: javascript, python

I am programming a football mashup application in google app engine and i'm having some trouble with specific videos when JwPlayer is trying to use them due to the title having either " or ' in.

I basically have this in JavaScript

```
{image: "{{y.thumbnail.hqDefault}}", file: "{{y.player.default}}", title: "{{y.title}}"}
```

Python writes y.title however some titles that come from youtube have the " or ' in.

```
{image: "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/UFOdqwhOs3c/hqdefault.jpg", file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFOdqwhOs3c&feature=youtube_gdata_player", title: "ZABALETA: "JOE HART IS THE MAN" | Man City 1 - 2 Barcelona | UEFA Champions League"},
```

In the occasion above the title has " but some other videos have ' in the titles.

How can I stop the " or ' from being recognised and just show the title as a normal string?

Answer (score 0):

Try the templatetag |escape (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-escape)

```
{image: "{{y.thumbnail.hqDefault|escape}}", file: "{{y.player.default|escape}}", title: "{{y.title|escape}}"}
```